# Existe alguma forma de substituir esses ifs?

Tags: javascript, if

```js
  if(inputUsuario >= 16.15 && inputUsuario < 16.20){
    inputUsuario = 16.20;
  }    
  if(inputUsuario >= 16.00 && inputUsuario < 16.15){
    inputUsuario = 16.15;
  } 
  
  if(inputUsuario >= 15.55 && inputUsuario < 16.00){
    inputUsuario= 16.00;
  }     
  if(inputUsuario >= 15.50 && inputUsuario < 15.55){
    inputUsuario = 15.55;
  } 
  if(inputUsuario >= 15.45 && inputUsuario < 15.50){
    inputUsuario = 15.50;
  }
```

Esse código acima é uma adaptação que eu fiz de algo que estou desenvolvendo. Nesse caso, se o usuário digitar um valor entre 15.45 e 15.50, tenho que transformar o input dele em 15.50.

**Exemplo:** O usuário digitou 16.16, então eu tenho que transformar esse valor em 16.20.

O grande problema é que o usuário pode digitar um valor entre 07.00 e 23.30 e pra cada um desses valores eu preciso adicionar um if para fazer essa modificação. Existe alguma forma de eu substituir esses `ifs`?

Eu utilizo o valor final do *input* pra fazer uma busca em uma planilha, por esse motivo eu preciso modificar o valor dessa forma. O grande problema é que não existe um padrão.

Caso existisse um padrão, teria alguma forma de diminuir esses *ifs*? Por exemplo, se os *inputs* fossem de 0.30 em 0.30.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, **parece** ter um certo padrão: a cada intervalo de `0.05`, arredonda para cima com 2 casas decimais de precisão, ou algo assim (exceto no caso de `16.00` e `16.15`, que arredonda para `16.15`). Enfim, só com esses exemplos, é o que dá pra "adivinhar"...

Comment: @hkotsubo, obrigado pela ajuda =D. Mas é bem bizarro, as vezes os números aparecem de 0.30 em 0.30, as vezes e 0.05 em 0.05, então não existe um padrão muito bem definido.

Comment: Isso por acaso seriam horários?

Comment: **Orientação a quem quiser publicar uma resposta:**  o resultado da operação *deve ser o próprio valor de entrada* caso esse não esteja contido dentro faixa de ajustes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu não consegui ver um padrão então tem que lidar individualmente. Se tiver um padrão a pergunta está toda errada.

O que dá para fazer é criar um laço e usar uma tabela com os valores mínimo e máximo, diminui o código, mas o tratamento será individual.

Como a pergunta não dá maiores detalhes eu supus algumas coisas, mas está gerando o resultado esperando. Usando o trecho do código postado (precisa terminar as outras faixas):

```js
const tabela = [ { min : 15.45, max : 15.5 },
                 { min : 15.5, max : 15.55 },
                 { min : 15.55, max : 16 },
                 { min : 16, max : 16.15 },
                 { min : 16.15, max : 16.2 } ];
var input = 16.16;
var valor = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tabela.length; i++) {
    if (input >= tabela[i].min && input < tabela[i].max) {
        valor = tabela[i].max;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(valor);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/LessIf.js).

O valor 0 que que eu coloquei seria um valor padrão para adotar se não cair em nenhuma faixa. Esse valor precisa ser ajustado conforme a necessidade ou até fazer alguma verificação do que fazer quando não cair em alguma faixa. A pergunta não fala nada sobre isso e o trecho postado nela não mostra o que fazer nesse caso.

Se tivesse um padrão, um intervalo regular, fosse sempre igual ao máximo da faixa (e parece que é, mas sem um padrão na faixa) então daria para usar matemática e matar todos ou quase todos os `if`s.

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120006/discussion-on-answer-by-maniero-existe-alguma-forma-de-substituir-esses-ifs) - comentários fora de contexto e sinalizados foram removidos. Quem quiser prosseguir ou acompanhar, pode clicar no link fornecido.

Answer (score 1):

Eu percebi um padrão sim.

Ficaria mais ou menos com essa lógica:

```js
function adaptar(value) {
  // tratar exceções
  if (value >= 16 && value < 16.15) {
    return "16.15";
  }

  const inteiro = (value * 100);
  const modulo = inteiro % 5;
  if (modulo == 0) {
    return (inteiro / 100).toFixed(2);
  }
  const soma = 5 - modulo;
  return ((inteiro + soma) / 100).toFixed(2);
}

function test() {
  let input = document.getElementById("input");
  let resp = document.getElementById("resp");
  if (!input.checkValidity()) {
    input.reportValidity();
  } else {
    resp.innerHTML = adaptar(input.value);
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" oninput="test()" min="7" max="23.3" maxlenght="5" step="0.01">
<span id="resp"></span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Programação funcional é linda!
Tudo que você queria sem nenhum **IFs**.

```js
const tabela = [ { min : 15.45, max : 15.5 },
                 { min : 15.5, max : 15.55 },
                 { min : 15.55, max : 16 },
                 { min : 16, max : 16.15 },
                 { min : 16.15, max : 16.2 } ];
    var input = 16.16;
    var valor = tabela.filter((num) => {
        return input >= num.min && input < num.max;
    })[0].max;
    console.log(valor)
```

Comment: poderia ser também sem essas trocentas linhas da tabela

Comment: Misturando var e const. Você sabe ao menos a diferença entre um e outro?

Comment: O intuito dessa resposta foi apenas demonstrar a técnica de programação funcional usando filter em um array e não discutir tipos de variáveis/constantes, quanto ao objeto de dados, em uma aplicação real ele pode vir de várias formas diferentes.